ASP.NET Core 8 : Type on ViewDataDictionary
I have this problem : InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BookingPortal.Models.ViewModels.WarehouseViewModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'BookingPortal.Models.ViewModels.WarehouseViewModel'.
Here is my Controller:
    public IActionResult B2bBookingInsert()
    {
         ViewData["Title"] = "New Booking";
         List<WarehouseViewModel> warehouse =   bookingPortalService.
         GetWarehousesToChoseForInsert();
         return View("B2bWarehouseSelection" , warehouse);
    }

My Application Service :
        public List<WarehouseViewModel> GetWarehousesToChoseForInsert()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * from Warehouse";
            DataSet dataset = db.Query(query);
            var dataTable = dataset.Tables[0];
            var warehouseList = new List<WarehouseViewModel>();
            foreach (DataRow warehouseRow in dataTable.Rows) {
                WarehouseViewModel warehouse = WarehouseViewModel.FromDataRow(warehouseRow);
                warehouseList.Add(warehouse);
            }
            return warehouseList;
        }

My ViewModel "WarehouseViewModel :
namespace BookingPortal.Models.ViewModels;

public class WarehouseViewModel
{
    public int IdWarehouse {get; set;}
    public int Client {get; set;}
    public string? WarehouseCode {get; set;}
    public string? Descritpion {get; set;}
    public string? Street {get; set;}
    public string? Locality {get; set;}
    public string? Cap {get; set;}
    public string? City {get; set;}
    public string? Nation {get; set;}
    public string? Telephone {get; set;}
    public string? Email {get; set;}
    public string? ActiveWeb {get; set;}
    public string? Active {get; set;}
    public string? Interlocutor {get; set;}
    public string? Latitude {get; set;}
    public string? Longitude {get; set;}
    public string? ActiveLoad {get; set;}
    public string? ActiveUnload {get; set;}
    public string? WarehouseInformationInSelect {get; set;}
    

    public static WarehouseViewModel FromDataRow(DataRow warehouseRow)
    {
        var warehouseViewModel = new WarehouseViewModel {
            IdWarehouse = Convert.ToInt32(warehouseRow["IdWarehouse"]),
            Client =  Convert.ToInt32(warehouseRow["Client"]),
            WarehouseCode = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["WarehouseCode"]),
            Descritpion = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Descritpion"]),
            Street = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Street"]),
            Locality = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Locality"]),
            Cap = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Cap"]),
            City = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["City"]),
            Nation = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Nation"]),
            Telephone = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Telephone"]),
            Email = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Email"]),
            Interlocutor = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Interlocutor"]),
            Latitude = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Latitude"]),
            ActiveLoad = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["ActiveLoad"]),
            ActiveUnload = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["ActiveUnload"]),
            WarehouseInformationInSelect = Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Descritpion"]) + " , " + Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Street"]) + " , " + Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Locality"])  + " , " +  Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["City"]) + " , " + Convert.ToString(warehouseRow["Cap"]) 
        };
        return warehouseViewModel;
    }
}

My Content View "B2bWarehouseSelection"  : I've kept it to a minimum to present the problem to you
@model List<WarehouseViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New Booking";
}
@foreach (var Item in Model) {
    <div>Warehouse</div>
}

I expect the view to open normally since I'm presenting a type  like the model it's typed on

Well the error says that you are passing a List but the ViewDataDictionary wants only a single model.

Could you share full code about Content View "B2bWarehouseSelection"  ? Do you use WarehouseViewModel in somewhere ?
